# how to separate several "a little bit connected" projects?

Tags: c#

The main class in my program is `OrderBook` of some stock.

- one part of my program, let's call it, `NYSE Connector` reads data from `NYSE` and constructs `OrderBook` of some stocks
- second part of my program, let's call it `LSE Connector` also constructs `OrderBook` of other stocks but from different exchange and by completely different algorithm
- third part of my program manages all set of `OrderBook` and produce different signals to different connectors (buy such stock on LSE sell another on NYSE etc.)

All parts of my program share the same instances of `OrderBook`. But parts itself are pretty independent. For example I can just run `NYSE Connector` without running anything else. Then I will just collect `OrderBook`. Doesn't make much sense, but possible.

Also I need everything to work asap, because even 1 ms is very important for me.

So now I just placed everything in one project (but in different folders), but I think it is not very good. If I will need another connector - I will just create one another folder.

How can I better separate my parts? But remember I need to share the same `OrderBook` instances.

Comment: This question is too broad.  Can you narrow it down to a more specific example, preferably with code?  So far I think you have two exchange connectors that are both creating their own order book instances, and so I am confused about why you'd want to share them.

Comment: it sounds like it's separated to me and if adding a new order book source means adding a new folder/namespace and implementing a source, then the separation is good. "better" separation can only be answered by determining the environment/context in which the source objects are used. it's more than just lines of code that determine "best" ____________

Comment: @ChrisShain because there are third part, which uses all `OrderBook` from all connectors.

Comment: i was thinking that probably i can create separate projects, but can two project share the same instance of some class... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be a vague answer, because this is a vague question.  Based off of your name (javapowered), I am going to assume that you are coming from a java background and as such I'll try to couch my answer in terms of java equivalence.

In .NET your unit of compiled code is an assembly.  The output of each project in a solution is usually exactly one assembly (not always, but for the purposes of discussion lets say it is just one).  Assemblies are roughly analogous to Java jar files, in that they contain the bytecode for compiled classes.  They are actually significantly more sophisticated than jar files, but that's more or less irrelevant to this answer.

Assemblies can contain references to (read: dependencies on) other assemblies.  Unlike the implicit class-by-class dependencies in java, .NET assembly dependencies are explicit and at the assembly level, e.g. assembly foo.bar depends on assembly foo.bat.  .NET assembly references must be a directed acyclic graph, meaning that you cannot have any loops where assembly A depends on B which in turn depends on A.  The runtime must be able to load all of an assembly's dependencies.

In your case, what I'd expect to see is 4 or more projects:

1. A main project.  Probably your executable.  This would have references to (depend on) all of the other projects.
2. A library project.  This would have no references to other projects within the solution.
3. A connector project for NYSE, referencing the library project.
4. A connector project for LSE, referencing the library project.

All of the classes that were common to all of the projects (`OrderBook`, other data structures, etc) would go in Library, where they can be references from anywhere that they are needed.

All of the exchange-specific implementations would go in their own exchange-specific assemblies.  This might include protocol handlers that are exchange-specific, subclasses of `OrderBook`, whatever.  If it is specific to an exchange, it goes in 3 or 4 above.

Finally all user interaction logic, control flow, etc would go in the main executable.

Comment: That sounds very good! Are there any examples how to do that? I.e. kind of `hello world` which will show how to reference one project from another. Will I have perfomance overhead because of many projects? peformance for me even more important than usability.

Comment: There won't be any measurable performance overhead from breaking the solution up into multiple projects, no.  As for a "how to" I'd strongly recommend that you pick up a C# book, if for no other reason than it will contain this information.

Comment: so there are no overhead? will I have one "executable" file as a result? any perfomance overhead likely not acceptable for me

Comment: i think a good start would be to create "library" project and to move `OrderBook` class there? however I don't know how to do that.

Comment: There is only the overhead of loading the assemblies at the start of the application.  The library project would start from the "Class Library" project template in visual studio.  Again, I ***strongly*** suggest you get a good book on C# development.

Comment: This one looks like it covers this topic: http://www.amazon.com/2010-NET-Platform-Andrew-Troelsen/dp/1430225491/ref=pd_sim_b_4

Comment: thanks, i'm reading it. am i correct that "library project" should be "dll"?

Comment: @ChrisShaing so you absolutely sure that after the project is loaded there are absolutely no difference if I have one exe file that contains everything or if I have one exe file + several dlls? from perfomance point of view.

Comment: There will be no *meaningful* performance impact. Certainly nothing compared to doing network and disk I/O (which you will certainly need to do in a trading application)

Comment: why should I have even *meaningful* performance impact? what is principal difference if I declare class in library or inside application? dll is read from disk only *once* isn't it?